# How loops can be vectorized? What vector operations can be implemented by loops

Tags: loops, vectorization

Could you give me an example of how a loop can be vectorized? For example, I have the following loop:

```
for (i=1; i < N; i++) {
     a[i] = b[i]*c[i];
     d[i] = a[i-1] + 7;
}
```

I know that there should not be any dependency before vectorizing the loop, but what after you show that there is no dependency. How exactly it can be vectorized, what steps?

Comment: What language is this? It may be obvious, but you shoul still specify it in your question.

Comment: This is wrong. Say, i = 0, then you are setting a[11] = b[0]*c[0], but next statement you want to set d[0] as a[4*N] + 7, obviously, a[4*N] might not have been initialized/assigned yet. So this data dependency has to be resolved first.

Comment: @Jubobs and DebasishJana, even though a language is not specified and given example is not the best one, but still I want try understand further steps for vectorization. Or you could give your own example and show how it can be done with assumption that there is no dependence.
Thanks

Comment: Unless you ask about a specific language, I think this question is either *too broad* or *unclear* (or both) to be a good fit on Stack Overflow. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Jubobs, let's say in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me from your question if you're asking about how to vectorize it manually or if you're asking how vectorizing compilers do that. So I'm going to just explain how compilers do that<sup>1</sup>, and you can always repeat the same steps manually if you want. Let's use as an example vectorizing to width 4.

Original code:

```
for (i=1; i < N; i++) {
  a[i] = b[i]*c[i];
  d[i] = a[i-1] + 7;
}
```

First, the compiler needs to identify that while iteration n depends on iteration n-1, this is a false dependency, because there's no data-flow dependency - `a[n]` does not depend on `a[n-1]`. Once this is identified, the compiler can perform [loop fission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_fission)<sup>2</sup>:

```
for (i=1; i < N; i++) {
  a[i] = b[i]*c[i];
}
for (i=1; i < N; i++) {
  d[i] = a[i-1] + 7;
}
```

Both of these can now be vectorized; let's focus on the first one, but it would be the same for the other. So our code is:

```
for (i=1; i < N; i++) {
  a[i] = b[i]*c[i];
}
```

For our example, let's assume the vectorization width is 4. The key for vectorization is [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling). So the compiler unrolls to size 4:

```
int i = 1;
// Unrolled loop:
for (; i < N-3; i+=4) {
  a[i]   = b[i]  *c[i];
  a[i+1] = b[i+1]*c[i+1];
  a[i+2] = b[i+2]*c[i+2];
  a[i+3] = b[i+3]*c[i+3];
}
// Remainder loop:
for (; i < N; i++) {
  a[i] = b[i]*c[i];
}
```

It's now obvious how to vectorize - the compiler changes<sup>3</sup> the identical sequence of instructions in the unrolled loop into a single vector instruction:

```
int i = 1;
// Unrolled loop:
for (; i < N-3; i+=4) {
  a[i:i+3] = b[i:i+3]*c[i:i+3];
}
// Remainder loop:
for (; i < N; i++) {
  a[i] = b[i]*c[i];
}
```

And later, during the later "lowering" phase of the compiler, it will assign an actual instruction for that operation - for example, if these are single-precision floating-point arrays on an SSE-enabled architecture, it will probably use [`mulps`](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/iscenter-new/mpc/altix/altixdata/opt/intel/vtune/doc/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc210.htm).

<sub>1 In a simplified manner, of course.

2 Keep in mind loop fission in this case actually hurts data locality.

3 Compilers don't really have to unroll and only then look for duplicates - those steps are typically taken together.</sub>

Comment: only thing I cannot understand why did you put the following code?

`// Remainder loop:
for (; i < N; i++) {
  a[i] = b[i]*c[i];
}`

Comment: @Mikon when unrolling a loop you need to create a remainder loop to deal with cases where the number of iterations is not divisible by the unroll width.